# Why is the determinant of a square matrix equal to the determinant of the diagonal of an SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

If I have a square matrix $A$, where $ A = UDV^T $ is the SVD of $A$,
how can $\det A = \pm \det D$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant has a [multiplicative property:](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product)

$$\det(UDV^t) = \det(U)\det(D)\det(V^t)$$

Now you just need to use a certain property of $U$ and $V$.

Comment: Thanks @flawr! I'm assuming the certain property of $U$ and $V$ you're referencing is that they are orthogonal which means their determinant is $\pm$1?

Comment: @adamcasey Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $D$ has on the diagonal the nonnegative square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ (counted with their multiplicity).

Note that the product of the eigenvalues (counted with their multiplicity) equals the determinant of the matrix. Thus
$$
(\det(D))^2=\det(A^TA)=\det(A^T)\det(A)=(\det(A))^2
$$